# reading a txt. file into a 2D list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a blank 10x10 .txt file (that contains few '*') into a 10x10 2D list (called grid) but I'm not getting anywhere. I need someone's help who can kindly augment this into a functional program please.

I have tried augmenting the code but it's not really working.

```py
SIZE = 10
file = open ("6complex.txt", "r")
line = file. read line ()
grid = []
grid = [
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
[" "," ", " "," ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
]

c = -1
r = -1
c = 0
for r in range (0, SIZE, 1):
for c in range (0, SIZE, 1):
element = grid[r][c]
grid. append(element)
print(grid)
```

Comment: ```line = file. readlines()``` will get the lists of the line, then split every line into fields.

Comment: what you post is invalid Python, Python uses indentation

Comment: what is the use of declaring variables `c` and `r` before the `for` loop, use `with ... as ...:` to read the file, you don't do a thing with `line`

Comment: have you tried the wonderful tool called a debugger

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is a `6complex.txt` file that contains a few `*` where if you find a star you will append it to the 2D grid else that position of the grid will have a blank space.

```
file = open("6complex.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()
grid = []

for line in lines:
    single_line = line.strip()
    single_line_array = []
    for ch in single_line:
        if ch=='*':
            single_line_array.append(ch)
        else:
            single_line_array.append(' ')
    grid.append(single_line_array)
    
print(grid)
```